# Does increasing the variance increase the value of a function?

Tags: probability, distributions, optimization, random-variable, entropy

Let $V=\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_iX_i$  where $X_i's$ are IID $\sim Bern(q)$ and $V$ with  $\sum a_i=k$. Note that $a_i$'s are non-negative integers.

I have a function $f$ as given below :
$$
f= \max_{q} h\left(E\left[e^{-\frac{1}{V +1}}\right]\right)-E\left[h\left(e^{-\frac{1}{V +1}}\right)\right]
$$

where $E(\cdot)$ denotes expectation w.r.t $V$ and $h(p)=-p \log _{2} p-(1-p) \log _{2}(1-p)$ is the binary entropy function.

**My simulations indicated that the value of $f$ increases as the number of non-zero entries in $[a_1,a_2,\ldots a_k]$ decreases.** Note that $q$ can be chosen to be different for different $\vec{a}=[a_1,\ldots a_k]$.

I am trying to come up with formal proof for this (as well as an intuitive explanation if possible). Can anyone help me formally establish this?

Example:

Let $k$=8. Consider the following $\vec{a}$ values:

1. $\vec{a}=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$
2. $\vec{a}=[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]$
3. $\vec{a}=[4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]$
4. $\vec{a}=[8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]$

I noticed that case 4 leads to maximum value for $f$ while case 1 has the lowest $f$.
The below figure illustrates these simulation results. For instance, Case 4 above has Hamming weight 1 and $f \approx 0.24.$  Case 1 has Hamming weight 8 and $f \approx 0.07$.

[image: Simulation result]

Comment: You might as well just edit this one.  If, subsequently, the preceding comments look confusing, we can just delete them.  I wonder what exactly you mean, though, by decreasing the number of non-zero entries.  Are you hoping that the value of $f$ for *all* nonzero $k-1$-tuples is larger than $f$ for *any* nonzero $k$-tuple? That seems (highly) unlikely.

Comment: @whuber I modified the question. Yes, I am hoping that the value of $f$  increases as hamming weight of $\vec{a}$ decreases  **for a given $\sum a_i$.**

Comment: Not a chance.  Although this happens *on average,* the spread of values of $f$ makes it easy to find counterexamples.

Comment: The question really doesn't make a lot of sense.  The reason is that whenever $X_i=0,$ the term $a_i$ does not contribute to $V,$ effectively making the number of non-zero $a_i$ one smaller.  This becomes increasingly apparent as $q$ grows small, for then very few of the $a_i X_i$ are nonzero. In short, changes in $q$ are confounded with changes in $k.$  Take, e.g., $q=1/8$ where $f(a=(1,7))=0.098$ but $f(a=(2,3,3))=0.11.$ (Again, I hope I'm calculating correctly!)

Comment: @whuber Thank you. I see what you are saying. Actually, I forgot to include a major detail (sorry !) which is that for any given $\vec{a}$ we can choose $q$ so as to maximize $f$. Thus, indeed $q$ is not same for different $\vec{a}$'s. I am editing the question with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function $f$ has the form

$$ h(\mathbb E(Y)) - \mathbb E (h(Y)) $$

which (for any function $h$) becomes zero when $\text{var}(Y) \to 0$ (that is, when the distribution of $Y$ becomes a $\delta$-function). So, intuitively it should be clear why $f$ increases when the variance of $Y$ increases.

To see this a bit more formally, you could look at the Taylor expansion of $h$ around $\bar Y=\mathbb E(Y)$ (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables))

$$ \mathbb E (h(Y)) = h(\bar Y) + \frac{1}{2} h''( \bar Y)\sigma_Y^2 + \frac{1}{3!}h^{(3)}(\bar Y)\mathbb E [(Y-\bar Y)^3] \;+ \; ... $$

(Note that since $Y = e^{-\frac{1}{V+1}}$ is bounded between $e^{-1}$ and $e^{-\frac{1}{k+1}} < 1$ then the higher moments are exponentially decreasing in magnitude)

The leading order term of the difference is proportional to the variance of $Y$. Specifically for your $h(p)$ with  $h''(p) = -\frac{1}{p(1-p)}$,

$$ f \approx \max_q \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{2\bar Y (1 - \bar Y) } > 0$$

Since $Y$ is a function of $V$ it's variance is roughly proportional to that of  $V$ which is  $\text{var}(V) = \sum_i a_i^2 \text{var}(X_i) = q(1-q)\sum_i a_i^2$, and it is easy to see that for fixed $k$ the variance of $V$ is minimal when all the $a_i$'s are equal and is maximal when only one $a_i$ is non zero.

Intuitively therefore, when you keep $k$ fixed and change the number of non zero elements of $a$ you are increasing $\sigma_Y^2$ while keeping $\bar Y$ roughly fixed, so the overall function value increases. And Since this is true for any fixed $q$ it should remain true after maximizing w.r.t $q$. (That is, if for some $\vec a_1$ and $\vec a_2$, $f(\vec a_1,q) \ge f(\vec a_2,q)$ holds for all $q$, then $\max_q f(\vec a_1,q) \ge \max_q f(\vec a_2,q)$)

Of course this is a very rough approximation and the details will have to be worked out much more carefully in order to make any sort of a definite statement. Specifically note that the above expression diverges when $\bar Y \to 1$ which can happen when $k \to \infty$, so none of this may be true for large enough $k$.

Comment: Could you please clarify how can we say "it should remain true after maximizing w.r.t $q$".? I understand your explanation for a fixed $q$ but the optimal $q$ can be different as the number of non zero elements of $a$ changes right?

Comment: I added a clarification. if  $f(\vec a_1,q) \ge f(\vec a_2,q)$ holds for all $q$, then $\max_q f(\vec a_1,q) \ge \max_q f(\vec a_2,q)$, even if the optimal $q$ is different. Hope this is clearer now

Comment: I understand it now.  Sorry for the confusion.